# How to read the last digit of each line in a text file?

Tags: java

I am making a program that reads data in text files. I also need to know the last number of each line in that file. I was wondering if there is a simply way of doing this.

text file example:

Name: Bob DOB: 1995-04-11 ID: **1**

Name: Bill DOB: 1992-07-12 ID: **2**

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: Read every line, discard everything except the last digit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with the following one liner:

`Files.lines(path).forEach(s -> System.out.println(s.charAt(s.length() - 1)));`

Comment: and what about if the last digit is in another position?

Comment: @JuanCarlosMendoza, as OP has shown, the last digit will always be the last character in a line in his file.

Comment: @JuanCarlosMendoza this fits the two examples in the question. I don't this the actual data differs.

Comment: Yes I know that this matches with the example. It's just that when I read _"I also need to know the last number of each line in that file"_ looks to me that it could be in another position.